# How can I convert a custom type to a string?

Tags: go

I'm using a package and instead of returning a `string`, it returns a `economy.ClassId` You can see [here](http://godoc.org/github.com/Philipp15b/go-steam/economy)

I want to pass the `economy.ClassId` which is just a string of numbers like "531569319" to a function that takes a string not a `economy.ClassId` so is there a way to convert this type to a string or no. Thanks.

I know you could like `strconv.FormatUint()` but what would I use for a custom type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ClassId` is declared as `type ClassId uint64`, so although a `ClassId` isn't exactly the same as a `uint64`, they have the same *underlying type*, and you can therefore *convert* from one to the other. To convert a value `x` to type `T` (when permitted), you write `T(x)`. So, in your case:

```
 funcThatTakesAString(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(classId), 10))
```

Comment: [`strconv.FormatUint`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint) takes two arguments.

Answer (score 6):

more generally you could implement the stringer interface on your type https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer

```
func (c ClassId) String() string {
    return strconv.FormatUint(uint64(c),10)
}
```

and use that otherFunc(classId.String())

http://play.golang.org/p/cgdQZNR8GF

PS: also acronymes (ID) should be all capitals

http://talks.golang.org/2014/names.slide#6

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that is perhaps more idiomatic is to use [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) using Go's [format string specification](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

Two examples...

The following converts the classId into a string base 10 number:

`classIDStr := fmt.Sprintf("%d", classId)`

The following converts it into a string hexadecimal number, with a-f digits in lower case:

`classIDHex := fmt.Sprintf("%x", classId)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of converting custom types which have an underlying `string` type back to `string`:

```golang
type CustomType string

const (
    StereoType CustomType = "stereotype"
    ArcheType CustomType  = "archetype"
)

func printString(word string) {
    println(word)
}
```

Now if you call `printString(StereoType)`, you'll get a compilation error saying

```
cannot use StereoType (constant "stereotype" of type CustomType) as type string in argument to printString
```

**The solution** is to cast it back to a `string` like this:

```golang
printString(string(StereoType))
```